# I can't stop the asynchronous

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, node.js, mongodb

So I am trying to get an array with a loop and the asynchronous nature of nodejs is killing me. Here is my code:

```js
 getDevices(userIDs, function(result) {
   if (result) {
    sendNotification(messageUser, messageText, result);
    res.send("Success");
   } else {
    res.send("ERROR");
   }
 });
 
});

function getDevices(userIDs, callback) {
 var userDevices = [];
 var device = [];
 
 for (var i = 0; i < userIDs.length; i++) {
   searchRegisterDevices(userIDs[i], function(result) {
    if (result) {
     for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
      device = {platform: result[j].platform, token: result[j].token};
      userDevices.push(device);  
     }
    } else {
     console.log("ERROR");
    }
   }); 
 }
 callback(userDevices);
}
```

```js
function searchRegisterDevices(userID, callback) {
 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
  } else {
   console.log("We are connected");
  }
  
  var collection = db.collection('RegisteredDevices');
  collection.find({userID: userID}).toArray(function (err, result) {
   if (err) {
             console.log("Error: " + err);
         } else if (result.length) {
    callback(result);
          } else {
             console.log('No document found');
         }
         db.close();
     });
 });
```

I first need to get all my devices out of my mongodb collection that match the ID in userIDs. SO userIDs is an array of IDs that are tied to devices in the collection. Once I get the device I need to get the device token out of the returned object.

So:
1) call getDevices passing an array of userIDs
2) call searchRegisterDevices with a device ID.
3) searchRegisterDevices returns an array of devices.
4) get the device token/s out of that array and push to userDevices array.
5) return userDevices array
6) call sendNotification with the array of userDevices

I know my issues, I just am having a hard time solving them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting user device for each user you should get them using single query:
 First: It will reduce number of calls
 Second: It will save you to handle callbacks o/p.

For it use $in operator.

Change searchdevices method:

```
function searchRegisterDevices(userID, callback) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("We are connected");
            }

            var collection = db.collection('RegisteredDevices');
            collection.find({
                    userID: {
                        $in: userIDs
                    }).toArray(function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error: " + err);
                    } else if (result.length) {
                        callback(result);
                    } else {
                        console.log('No document found');
                    }
                    db.close();
                });
            });
    }
```

It will return array of userdevices for passed userids.

Comment: At first I was going to complain saying this wouldn't work. Then it hit me. THIS WORKS PERFECT. I can't believe I didn't think of this. Instead of searching for each device, this returns an array of every device of every ID. Perfect. Upvote!

Comment: @AustinHunter I am glad that It helped you. :)